# Using freetds and unixODBC to run queries with accents (á,é,í,ó,ú) on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-14.04, freetds, unixodbc

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04** with **freetds** and **unixODBC** to connect to a **2008 Microsoft SQL Server**. I tested the connection with `tsql` and `isql` and it worked correctly. While using `isql -v` if I include accents (á,é,í,ó,ú) in the query I receive the following response:

> [37000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '?'.
>
> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute

While installing freetds and unixODBC packages I received a warning message saying that special characters would not be accepted unless an extra package was but I can't which one it was. To try and solve this problem I uninstalled freetds and unixODBC, reinstalled them and did not receive any warning message but I am still receiving the same error message when including accents in the queries.

PS: This is the first question I make so sorry if it is vague or incomplete.

Comment: what is your concern here .. i think  after reinstalling all started working properly if yes there could some dependency of configuration issue...

Comment: After reinstalling I am still receiving the same error message when including accents in the query

Comment: which ODBC  driver you are using it is issue of utf16   use  latest version of ODBC  at least later than3.5.  https://www.progress.com/tutorials/odbc/unicode

Comment: When I run `tsql -C` it responds 'TDS version: 4.2' and when I connect to the server with `tsql` it responds:
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
How may I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying for a long while the solution I found was quite simple and worked with `tsql` and `isql`. On the data source file for unixODBC I needed to set `TDS_Version=8.0`.

The file before:

> [MSSQL]
>
> Driver = FreeTDS
>
> Server = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
>
> Port = XXXX
>
> Database = name

The new file:

> [MSSQL]
>
> Driver = FreeTDS
>
> Server = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
>
> Port = XXXX
>
> TDS_Version = 8.0
>
> Database = name

Comment: Note for future readers: FreeTDS aliases TDS version "8.0" to TDS version 7.1 for compatibility, but warns that specifying "8.0" should be avoided. See the "Regarding obsolete versions" section of [Choosing a TDS protocol version](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm) for details.